# Замена строк в файле по номеру на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы, замена

У меня есть 3 txt файла: inter.txt (файл содержащий интервалы)

```
2-4
8-10
13-14
```

lesno.txt (исходный фай времени)

```
00:00:16
00:00:10
00:00:25
00:00:11
00:00:16
00:00:03
00:00:05
00:00:16
00:00:22
00:00:32
00:00:16
00:01:01
00:00:06
00:00:16
00:00:11
```

bitty.txt (измененное время)

```
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:00:01
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:01
00:00:01
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в файле lesno.txt в интервалы указанные в inert.txt вставить новые значения из bitty.txt и можно всё в новый файл newlesno.txt

```
00:00:16
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:00:01
00:00:16
00:00:03
00:00:05
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:16
00:01:01
00:00:01
00:00:01
00:00:11
```

Есть часть кода, которая текстовые интервалы переносит в python-список:

```py
inter = []

with open('inter.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_inp:
    inter_lines = f_inp.readlines()

    for i in range(len(inter_lines)):
        x, y = map(float, inter_lines[i].split('-'))

        inter.append((x, y))     # x - начало интервала y - конец
```

Но вот как дальше быть не знаю. Пробовал разные варианты, в основном все заканчивалось тем, что оно все копирует и из 15 строк выходит 45-100...

Вопрос: Как заменить строки в файле по известным номерам строк?

Comment: Прочитайте строки файла в список, измените записи по соответствующим индексам, запишите в новый файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
import numpy as np
#читаем все файлы в списки:
lesno = [x.strip() for x in open(r'lesno.txt', 'r').readlines()]
inter = [x.strip() for x in open(r'inter.txt', 'r').readlines()]
bitty = [x.strip() for x in open(r'bitty.txt', 'r').readlines()]

#собственно, код:
res = np.empty_like(lesno)              #создаем пустой numpy-массив по подобию lesno
for i in inter:                         #и заполняем его значениями из bitty в 
    bounds=list(map(int, i.split('-'))) #соответствии с интервалами в inter
    for j in range(bounds[0]-1, bounds[1]):
        res[j] = bitty.pop(0)

mask=(res =='')  #создаем маску пустых элементов полученного массива
res[mask] = np.array(lesno)[mask] #заполняем пустые элементы значениями из lesno
```

Ну и получаем:

```
print(res.tolist()) #вывод на печать с преобразованием из массива numpy в обычный список
```

> ['00:00:16', '00:00:03', '00:00:02', '00:00:01', '00:00:16', '00:00:03', '00:00:05', '00:00:05', '00:00:06', '00:00:07', '00:00:16', '00:01:01', '00:00:01', '00:00:01', '00:00:11']

а уж полученный список обрабатывайте дальше, как сами знаете.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо просто считать все строки файла в список, изменить в этом списке элементы с нужными номерами и записать этот список в файл (не в конец, а поверх того что было). Вот наивный пример того, как это можно осуществить:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
list_strings = f.readlines()
print(list_strings)     # ['строка1\n', 'строка2\n', 'строка3']
f.close()

f = open('file.txt', 'w')
list_strings[1] = 'строка55\n'  # Вместо 1 номер строки, которую нужно заменить
f.writelines(list_strings)
f.close()

f = open('file.txt', 'r')
list_strings = f.readlines()
print(list_strings)     # ['строка1\n', 'строка55\n', 'строка3']
f.close()
```